# Integrating $\rm x^ae^{-bx}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I've encountered this integral many, many times (exams, exercises) and always end up wasting a bit of time calculating it for different $\rm a,b$'s.

Is there any way to calculate the following integral?

$$\rm \int x^ae^{-bx}dx.\quad  a,b \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}.$$

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, you can apply $a$ rounds of integration by parts.

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, that's what I've been doing, but I wanted a 'closed form' of this, without having to do parts everytime I encounter a different $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

There is a representation in terms of the Gamma function if you want this for general $a$ and $b$... For integer $a$ and $b$, integration by parts will suffice
$$ \int x^ae^{-bx}dx$$
$$= -\frac{x^ae^{-bx}}{b}+\frac{a-1}{b}\int x^{a-1}e^{-bx}\,dx$$
Now just recursively apply this rule to the final integral... you'll soon find a pattern emerging
$$= -\frac{x^ae^{-bx}}{b}+\frac{a-1}{b}\left[-\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-bx}}{b}+\frac{a-2}{b}\int x^{a-2}e^{-bx}\,dx\right]$$
$$= -\frac{x^ae^{-bx}}{b} -\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-bx}(a-1)}{b^2}+\frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{b^2}\int x^{a-2}e^{-bx}\,dx$$
$$= -\frac{x^ae^{-bx}}{b} -\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-bx}(a-1)}{b^2}+\frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{b^2}\left[-\frac{x^{a-2}e^{-bx}}{b}+\frac{a-3}{b}\int x^{a-3}e^{-bx}\,dx\right]$$
$$=-\frac{x^ae^{-bx}}{b} -\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-bx}(a-1)}{b^2}-\frac{x^{a-2}e^{-bx}(a-1)(a-2)}{b^3}+\frac{(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)}{b^3}\int x^{a-3}e^{-bx}\,dx$$

Pattern matching, the rule appears to be, $\forall \{a,b\} \in  \Bbb N$:
$$\int x^ae^{-bx}dx = \color{red}{-\frac{e^{-bx}}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a} \frac{x^{a-k}(a)_{k+1}}{b^{k+1}}}$$
That last sum might be a little off as I was quickly looking, so feel free to check me as an exercise. You should get the basic idea though.

Comment: What does this *indefinite* integral have to do with the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: @AlexM.
First note that, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[\int_{g(x)}^{\infty} h(t) \,dt\right] = -h(g(x))g'(x)$$
Also, the definition of the Incomplete Upper Gamma Function is
$$\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^{\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt $$
Using these facts, we see that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \Gamma(a+1,bx) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{bx}^{\infty} t^{a}e^{-t}\,dt = -(bx)^ae^{-bx}b = -b^{a+1}x^ae^{-bx} \;[\forall x > 0]$$
Therefore, we get that
$$\int x^ae^{-bx}dx = \int b^{a+1}x^ae^{-bx}b^{-a-1} = -b^{-a-1}\int\left[\frac{d}{dx} \Gamma(a+1,bx)\right]dx = \color{red}{-b^{-a-1}\Gamma(a+1,bx)}$$

Comment: @AlexM. I would also like to point out that I hit the character limit ***exactly***, first try in my comment above simply pasting all this in from notepad (without checking length along the way). It's a Christmas miracle... I was really thinking I was going to go over the limit a bit. Hopefully that clears things up a bit. The Incomplete Gamma Function isn't something I mind using in the slightest (I love special functions), but some mathematicians much smarter than I am disagree with me, so I figured I would just leave the answer as it was :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is $\mathbf{no}$.

In particular, take $b=-1$ and $a=-1$. Then you are left with the integral:

$$ \int \frac{e^x}{x} dx$$

And it is well known that this integral has no "closed form" solution.

Claude gave an example of a solution that uses the incomplete gamma function, but this is generally seen as a "nonelementary" function.

Even if we require $a>0,b>0$, we can still find an example. Pick $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=1$. Then we have:
$$ \int \sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx$$

With the substitution $x=u^2$, this gives us:
$$ 2\int u^2e^{-u^2}du$$
And one iteration of iteration by parts leaves us with an integral of the form:
$$ \int e^{-u^2}du$$
Which is known to have no closed form.

Comment: I'm taking $a,b\geq 0$. Does that still not secure 'elementary function integrability'?

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in \mathbb N$ you can develop a finite length iterative reduction formula and collect it into a compact sum with sigma notation. I believe this is that the OP intended for his/her/-insert appropriate gender pronoun here- answer, as he/she/something did state non-negative integral a and b.